# How to replace a value in one map with the value of another map, based on a pattern match?

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming, maps, match

I have a map that has a few key value pairs, and I would like a way to go through those pairs and attempt to match the keys with the value of another map. If there's a match the values are substituted for each other. In other words, if there's a match value of the second map is substituted for the value of the first map. If there is no match, it is not included in the result.

I've tried figuring out the logic use the scala .map function but I'm new to scala and can't quite figure it out.

For example, I have the following two scala Map[String, String]:

```
val lookupMap = Map("aaa" -> "apple", "bbb" -> "orange", "ccc" -> "banana")

val entriesMap = Map("foo" -> "ccc", "bar"-> "aaa", "baz" -> "zzz")
```

I would like some way to get the following result:

```
val result = Map("foo" -> "banana", "bar" -> "apple")
```

Note: "baz" was not included because it did not match to anything in the lookup Map.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The first option you gave is exactly what I was looking for! Could you explain your thinking in plain English? I'm trying to learn the scala syntax and functional way of thinking. Also, what is the difference between this option and the second? I noticed it gave back a View, but I am not familiar with Views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `for` comprehension can clean that up.

```
val result = for {
               (k,ev) <- entriesMap
               lv     <- lookupMap.get(ev)
             } yield (k,lv)
//result: Map[String,String] = Map(foo -> banana, bar -> apple)
```

Comment: is this code safe? I ask because someone in the thread below brought up a point that I didn't put much thought into. What if a key does not exist? Will this throw an exception in any case? Or it does not concern itself with Some or None?

Comment: @jjaguirre394; Yes, it is safe. You can see for yourself that it steps through every entry in `entriesMap`, including `"baz"->"zzz",` and it delivers the correct result without throwing. This is because it calls `.get()` on the `lookupMap`, which returns an `Option[String]`. If the value exists (i.e. `Some("...")`) then it is unwrapped and assigned to the variable `lv`. If not then the `for` comprehension simply moves on to the iteration.

Comment: The requirements changed and it looks like now I have to look through a lookup of type Map[String, Map[String, String]]. The function I came up with looks like this `val res = for{ (k, ev) <- entriesMap
     | lv <- lookupMap.get(k).get(ev)} yield (k, lv)` but for some reason I am getting something like this as the result `Map(foo -> n)` where did the n come from?

Comment: @jjaguirre394; There isn't enough information in your comment to supply a confident answer. You'll probably want to submit a fresh question with sufficient details, including sample input and expected output. Until then all I can say is that `lookupMap.get(k).get(ev)` won't work because `lookupMap.get(k)` returns an `Option` and the `Option` type has no `.get(key)` method.

Answer (score 3):

Lets break down your problem in simpler steps.

1. Filter out all pairs on the `entriesMap` whose value does not exists as a key in the `lookupMap`.
2. Map the remaining pairs to change the value for the value on the `lookupMap` associated with the original value.

Thus, you can write the following:

```
val result =
  entriesMap
    .filter { case (_, value) => lookupMap.contains(key = value) }
    .map { case (key, value) => key -> lookupMap(value) }
```

However, every time that you want to `filter` and then `map`, you can always use `collect` *(which will do the same job, but in just one iteration)*.
Thus, you can write this:

```
val result = entriesMap.collect {
  case (key, value) if lookupMap.contains(key = value) => key -> lookupMap(value)
}
```

Now, one *"problem"* with the above code is that it uses the *unsafe* `apply` over a **Map**, which will throw an exception if they key does not exists.
Usually, one should use the `get` method, which would return the value wrapped on an **Option**, which will be a `None` if the key did not existed.

In this case, the access is not unsafe, because we are checking if the key exists before.
Anyways, one could rethink the program as:

1. Map the values of the `entriesMap` by attempting to get their associated value on the `lookupMap`.
2. Filter out the pairs where its values is now a `None` and unwrapping the `Somes`.

The code will be as follows:

```
val result =
  entriesMap
    .view // Only if you are in 2.13
    .mapValues(value => lookupMap.get(key = value))
    .collect { case (key, Some(value)) => key -> value }
    .toMap // This is necessary because mapValues returns a view, which is a lazy collection.
           // Other option would have been to use just map instead of mapValues.
```

Finally, instead of using higher order functions directly, one could use **for comprehension**.
Thus, this code *(almost the same as the one from jwvh's answer)*:

```
val result =
  for {
    (key, value) <- entriesMap // For each key-value pair in entriesMap...
    newValue <- lookupMap.get(key = value) // And for each newValue associated with each original value...
  } yield key -> newValue // Yield the key-newValue pair.
```